# update table from another table using like clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i am new to stackoverflow. Am stuck with this problem for weeks but am unable to find similar examples to this (correct me if i am wrong). What i am trying to achieve is updating the values of one table from another table but using a look alike keywords eg. I have 2 tables

> table1 (id, item) values:

```
id | item 
-------------
10 | book  
20 | copy   
30 | pen
```

> table2 (id,item) values:

```
id | item 
-------------
null | the big book  
null | the copy machine   
null | penpal
```

Now I want to:

```
Update table2 A
Set id = Select id From table1 B
               Where A.item Like B.item;
```

My desired outcome is:-

```
id | item 
-------------
10 | the big book  
20 | the copy machine   
30 | penpal
```

How do it do it? Thank you all.

Comment: Could there be entries like, say, 'the big book' AND 'the big heavy book' both in table2? If so, which one would you pick?

Comment: @Shruti: the one with the min rownum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table2 set id = 
  (select min(id) from table1 
     where table2.item like '%' || table1.item ||'%' );
```

Comment: yaay, it works just takes awhile to run it. just want to ask whether the query will take longer time/shorter time to update if i add and condition to the where clause. Thanks a lot. 

update table2 set id = 
  (select min(id) from table1 
     where table2.item like '%' || table1.item ||'%' and table2.item is null );

Comment: It will probably run faster if the where clause filters away a lot of rows, but on the other hand, it will probably run slower if almost all rows are still found by the where condition. You have to try.

Comment: yeah i tried..and the query is still running for more than 30 mins already. thanks anyway. :) worst come to worst will cron job it. :)

Comment: add a `where id = null and exists(...` *see other answers* `) and rownum<1000` clause (replace 1000 with an appropriate number) to do it in small pieces.

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot. i'm sorry but i would like to ask a silly question. may i know can i select aggregate of a column from 2 tables? 
I tried the below but got error of ambiguious columns. 
Select B.Min(Id) From Table2 A, Table1 B
Where A.item  Like '%' || B.item  || '%';
Appreciate u replying to me. Thank you.

Comment: You want `select min(b.id) ...`

Comment: hahah yes yes..i got it already. thanks. btw i am unable to update my table still (it's about 1.4 billion of records) takes about 6 hours n still no update..am still exploring other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Merge :

```
MERGE INTO Table2 tar
USING
(
     SELECT MIN(T1.ID) AS ID, T2.item AS item
     Table2 T2 
     LEFT JOIN
     Table1 T1
     ON (T2.item LIKE '%'||T1.item||'%')
     GROUP BY T2.item
 ) src
 ON (tar.item = src.item)

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET tar.id = src.id;
```

This solution may be faster.

Comment: Namaste shurti, thank you for ur time in answering. However i get the error below:- 

SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Table 1 = industry_token 
Table 2 =industry_validation
modified script used (correct me if i am wrong):-

Comment: UPDATE Industry_Validation_Test SET Industry_Validation_Test.Custnm = T.Custnm
FROM
(
     SELECT MIN(Industry_Token.Custnm_Token) AS Custnm_Token, T2.Custnm 
     Industry_Validation_Test T2 
     LEFT JOIN
     Industry_Token T1
     ON T2.Custnm LIKE '%'||T1.Custnm||'%'
     GROUP BY T2.Custnm
 ) T
 WHERE Industry_Validation_Test.Custnm = T.Custnm;

Comment: Hi Joey :) You seem to have missed a `FROM` after `T2.Custnm` in your select list for join. Also, shouldn't you be updating Custnm_Token value, not Custnm?

Comment: custnm of Industry_Validation_Test/ id of Table2. Thanks again shurti.

Comment: @shurti: don't seem to work. :( Apologies for any inconvenience caused. 
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

UPDATE Industry_Validation_Test SET Industry_Validation_Test.SIC_CODE = T.SIC_CODE
From
(    Select Min(T1.SIC_CODE) As SIC_CODE, T2.CUSTNM 
     From Industry_Validation_Test T2 
     LEFT JOIN Industry_Token T1
     ON T2.Custnm LIKE '%'||T1.CUSTNM_TOKEN||'%'
     GROUP BY T2.Custnm
 ) T
 WHERE Industry_Validation_Test.CUSTNM = T.CUSTNM_TOKEN;

thanks a lot for ur kind assistance.

Comment: yikes! I didn't realize you couldn't use updates with joins in Oracle. Apologies. Could you try this `MERGE INTO Industry_Validation_Test IVT
    
USING ( Select Min(T1.SIC_CODE) As SIC_CODE, 
    T2.CUSTNM AS CUSTNM
       
  From Industry_Validation_Test T2 
  
  LEFT JOIN Industry_Token T1 
       
        ON 
  
  (T2.Custnm LIKE '%'||T1.CUSTNM_TOKEN||'%') 
  
  GROUP BY T2.Custnm 
) SRC
        
ON (IVT.CUSTNM = SRC.CUSTNM)
 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET IVT.SIC_CODE = SRC.SIC_CODE;` ? I'll update my answer

Comment: hi @Shruti: thanks for the clarification. Am running the script for about 30 mins already but no response yet. will let u know once it is done..hopefully it'll be solved. thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @Joey you're welcome! Out of curiosity, how many records do you have?!
Also, don't forget to vote up if you found the answer useful, and accept an answer if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: i have about 1.4 billion of records hahahha..and tbh it's not updated yet..yes will definitely vote it up once the problem is solved. so far not yet hahahha..even after creating index, the script still still on scriptrunner task after 3 hours hahaha..still exploring other ways with less time.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table2 t2
set id = ( select min(id) from table1 t1 where item like '%' || t1.item || '%')
where exists ( select 1 from table1 t1 where item like '%' || t1.item || '%');
```